# Are symbols automatically generated when defining a variable in the global context and what are symbols?

Tags: variable-definitions, symbols

**Abstract:** I have noticed something really tricky with Mathematica and the documentation for symbols is short on clearing the confusion. It likely reveals what symbols are but it's not very prominent. I know unique symbols are created inside Modules but are they also generated every time we define regular functions and variables?

**About The Code:** I did a simple test with `abc = 123`. The output for `?abc` gives a grayed out `Symbol` and `SymbolName` produces an error message. Does this mean it is not a symbol?

```
abc = 123
?abc
SymbolName[abc]
```

**Four Questions:**

1. Are system functions symbols?
2. Are user defined functions symbols?
3. Are user defined variables symbols?
4. What are symbols and are they automatically generated?

Answer (score 4):

Towards your `abc` example which seems to be the source of confusion: At all times after evaluating `abc = 123`, `abc` is a symbol (with full name probably `` Global`abc ``, but that depends on the `Context[]` in which you evaluate it). The problem with `SymbolName[abc]` is that `abc` evaluates immediately to `123`. The latter is not a symbol, hence `SymbolName[123]` throws an error. One can obtain the behavior that you probably expected as follows:

```
SymbolName[Unevaluated[abc]]
```

> "abc"

Comment: Addendum: if you want to use that construct as a pure function, do it this way: `ff = Function[Null, SymbolName[Unevaluated[#]], {HoldFirst}]; ff[abc]`.

Comment: @J.M. could it be used in this form as well: `ff@abc`? Does this form omit the need to set attributes to `HoldFirst` when used in other contexts like Blocks or user defined functions? Question on the immediate assignment `ff = `. Shouldn't it be delayed assignment `ff := `?

Comment: @Jules: 1. yes; the attributes are already associated with the pure function `ff`. 2. `:=` would force repeated evaluation of the RHS, so that isn't what you want in that situation; `=` is the correct choice here.